# Two Hilbert $G$-bundles are isomorphic iff the representations of the little group are equivalent

Tags: rt.representation-theory, vector-bundles, topological-groups, group-actions, unitary-representations

While reading Mackey's "Unitary Group Representations in Physics, Probability and Number Theory", at page 66 I encountered the following statement (my reformulation):

> if $\mathcal K$ and $\mathcal K'$ are two $G$-bundles over the same base $S$ (on which $G$ acts transitively) and if $H \le G$ is the stabilizer subgroup of some $s_0 \in S$, and if $L, L'$ are the representations of $G$ in $L^2 (S, \mathcal K, \mu)$ and, respectively, $L^2 (S, \mathcal K', \mu)$, naturally induced by the actions of $G$ on $\mathcal K$ and $\mathcal K'$, then:
>
> $$\mathcal K \simeq \mathcal K' \iff L \Big| _H \simeq L' \Big| _H$$
>
> (i.e. the bundles are isomorphic if and only if the restrictions of the natural representations are unitarily equivalent).

Mackey gives no proof, and I've lost myself in it.

For the direct implication, I tried to proceed like this: if $\alpha : \mathcal K \to \mathcal K'$ is the isomorphism, letting $\alpha_0 : S \to S$ denote its natural restriction on the base $S$ allows us to define $U^s : \mathcal K _s \to \mathcal K _{s \alpha_0}$ by $(s, v) \alpha = (s \alpha_0, U^s v)$ (Mackey writes the actions and the isomorphism to the right); this then allows us to define $U : L^2 (S, \mathcal K, \mu) \to L^2 (S, \mathcal K ', \mu)$ by $U (\varphi) (s) = U^{s \alpha_0 ^{-1}} (\varphi (s \alpha_0 ^{-1}))$. The trouble is that this $U$ turns out not to be good for what I want to prove, and I can't think of anything else.

For the converse, it's even worse: the fact that those two representations are equivalent gives a unitary transformation between sections, but how does that allow me to get an isomorphism between the bundles?

Where do I use the transitivity of the actions, and how do I use that $H$ stabilizes $s_0$?

There is also the possibility that I have misunderstood Mackey's statement, since it is given in prose. For the converse, it is not clear whether $G$ acts on the bundles and we speak of the restrictions to $H$ of its natural representations, or if I consider $H$ to act on the bundles and then consider its natural representations, in which case there is no need to restrict anything anymore.

Comment: The statement in grey is wrong. Take for example $H$ which is normal in $G$ and not of finite index. Take two representations of $H$, the one dimensional trivial and the infinite dim trivial. Induce both to $K$ and $K'$ respectively. You get different Hilbert bundle, but $L|_H$ and $L'|_H$ both will be infinite dim trivial.

Comment: I don't have Macky's book at hand, but I suppose he relates the Hilbert bundle with the rep of $H$ on the fiber over $s_0$, not with the restriction of $L$.

Comment: @UriBader: You might be right. The book that I am reading is written mostly in prose, without proofs, in an attempt to give a conceptual, non-technical overview of the subject. This is why some statements, given somewhat informally, are ambiguous, leaving much to the interpretation of the reader.

Comment: How long is this "prose" part? What about pasting it in, instead of speculating?

Comment: @UriBader: I have reread that part with your interpretation in mind, and yes, it seems to make sense. Let me see whether I can do it by myself now.